# A version of the Nash-Moser inverse function for unbounded domains?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Do there exist versions of the Nash-Moser inverse function theorem applicable to spaces of *unbounded* smooth functions on unbounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Any reference would be appreciated but here is more specifically what I'm looking for:

1. I'm interested in a right inverse function theorem, i.e. the existence of right (but not left) inverse of the derivative is assumed.
2. The result should be applicable to semi-linear elliptic operators.
3. Since linear elliptic operators considered on the space of all smooth functions do not have linear right inverse, one expects that the relevant function space should be the space of smooth functions with derivatives of all orders that are of polynomial growth or something similar.

Comment: Nash-Moser is an inverse function theorem for a Fréchet space or a scale of Banach spaces, where the functional and the right inverse to the linearized operator are smooth tame. You get to choose which spaces and norms you want to use. This is usually determined by what kind of a priori estimates you can prove for the linearized PDE. In the situation you describe, it sounds like you need to use some kind of weighted Sobolev norm. Perhaps you could provide more details.

Comment: @DeaneYang, I'm interested in finding local right inverse of nonlinear operators $L$ given by $Lf=\Delta f + f^p$ for $f$ in some function space. I don't see how these can be set up in a weighted Sobolev space. The point is that there are no Sobolev multiplication theorems for weighted Sobolev spaces, as far as I know.

Comment: First, it occurs to me that for an elliptic PDE, you normally do not need Nash-Moser. The standard Banach space inverse function theorem with the right choice of a norm is usually good enough.

Comment: @DeaneYang, I'm aware of that and that's what I tried to do for a while. Unfortunately I didn't find any reference in which the Banach space inverse function theorem is used to solve elliptic semilinear equations in unbounded domains or even just in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: @DeaneYang, actually it's probably true that what is needed is a generalization of the Banach space inverse function in different direction, rather than Nash-Moser type of theorem. For example, this apparently neglected article looks promising to me: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19861290108

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about unbounded solutions of an elliptic PDE on an unbounded domain. So I probably can't help you. One more question: Do you know anything about unbounded solutions to the linearized equation: $$ \Delta f + Vf = h$$ where $V$ is an unbounded function?

Comment: @DeaneYang, I do not, but I suspect weighted Sobolev spaces would be natural for this kind of problem.

Comment: No point thinking about nonlinear equation if you can’t do the linear one.

Comment: @S.Z.  Can you give more details of exactly what you want to do with this operator $L$.  I know a bunch of references related to various forms of this equation.

Comment: @DeaneYang, I'm interested in inverting the operator $L$ around 0, so the linearized problem is simply $\Delta f=h$. The latter certainly has solutions for lots of unbounded $h$.

Comment: @Math604, sure, the specific problem is this: Find two locally convex spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $Y$ contains all smooth functions of polynomial growth at infinity such that $L:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $L(U)$ contains an open set of $Y$. Unfortunately in all references I have seen for this kind of inhomogeneous equations the right-hand side is assumed to be a function that decays at infinity.

Comment: @Math604, it should read $L(X)$, not $L(U)$ above.

Comment: "The latter certainly has solutions for lots of unbounded $h$". Yes, but that's not a helpful observation. The key, as I've said, is to find an a priori estimate for the equation $\Delta u + Vu = h$ in terms of $V$ and $h$. That will provide a guide to what norms or seminorms to use in the implicit function theorem. If no one else has done it yet, you'll need to do this yourself.

Comment: Note that the space of tempered distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Schwartz_space) has polynomial growth, so, given a smooth function $h$ with polynomial growth, it suffices to solve for a tempered distribution $u$ such that $\Delta u + Vu = h$, because elliptic regularity will imply that $u$ is in fact smooth. The standard way to do this is to prove an a priori estimate for the dual space, i.e., given any Schwarz function $v$, prove an estimate for a norm of $v$ in terms of a norm of $\Delta v + Vv$ (which is also Schwarz).

Comment: Another suggestion: Have you studied the spherical symmetric case (i.e, $f$ is a function of $|x|$ only)? I suggest doing that for both the linear equation and the linearized equation. It can also help guide you on what to do in the general case.

Comment: The references in this paper should provide some useful results and techniques: https://msp.org/pjm/2007/229-1/pjm-v229-n1-p03-s.pdf

Comment: @S.Z.  Thanks for the reply.   Are you able to tell me exactly what equation you want to solve and maybe what range of $p$.    If you look at the various papers of del Pino, Wei, Davila, Musso....  they have a bunch of papers related to linearizing techniques in various weighted spaces. If I knew more i can maybe give a better reference

Comment: @S.Z.   For instance are you looking for positive classical solution of something like $ -\Delta u(x)=u(x)^p + f(x)$ in the full space where you want to allow the case of $ f $ does not decay to zero at $\infty$?

Comment: @Math604, yes, that's the equation that I'm interested in, say for $p=3$ and space dimension $n>2$. Thank you for the reference, I just looked at few papers by these authors and it appears that decaying solutions (and decaying potentials) only.

Comment: @DeaneYang, Thank you for the suggestions. In fact, spaces of smooth functions of polynomial growth are defined in the classical books by Schwartz and Horvath on distribution theory. These are not Frechet spaces but are certainly complete locally convex spaces, so my plan is to apply to inverse function theorem from the paper that I linked in one of the comments above. The only problem is that this theorem has to be modified to become a 'right inverse' function theorem.

Comment: @S.Z.   Suppose we want a positive solution $u$ for some positive $f$ that does not decay to zero quick enough;  then i think there is no solution.  To see this multiply by a $ \phi^m$ ($m$ large)  where $ \phi=1$ in $B_R$ and compactly supported in $B_{2R}$.   Then integrate by parts and apply Holder and send $ R \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Math604, sorry, If I created the impression that I'm interested in positive solutions, I'm not, I'm interested in any solution. See my reply to your first comment, that's where the problem is stated precisely.

Comment: @S.Z.   Lets suppose we want to solve $ -\Delta u(x) = |u|^{p-1} u + f(x)$ in full space.   Is the question  " given a bounded $ f(x)$  but without imposing lots of decay,  try and find a solution $u(x)$''.  Is this roughly what you are interested in?

Comment: @Math604, yes, except that I'm interested in unbounded $f$, of polynomial growth at infinity.